# Trouble referencing buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, user-interface, actionscript

I am trying to create an interface that allows users to click on buttons and take them to certain frames.

```
stop();

home_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
graphics_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
animation_btn.onRelease {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like AS2, not AS3.  What exactly are you asking? Have you tried the above code and gotten errors?

Comment: I've tried this code and it didn't work, I get "Access of possibly undefined property onRelease through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton". I am trying to make a menu screen that has a list of buttons. When a user clicks on a button it will take them to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to code it in Actionscript 2 and not Actionscript 3 the only modification you need to make to the existing code is:

```
home_btn.onRelease = function() {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Same for the other two buttons, this is the correct syntax for AS2.

For AS3, you need to assign an event listener to the button that will execute a function whenever it is fired:

```
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeClick);

function homeClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and I still get ""Access of possibly undefined property onRelease through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton""

Comment: Ok so the project itself is an AS3 project, so AS2 code won't work. I'll update my answer with the correct AS3 code.

Comment: Then in Flash select the stage and under the properties tab set `Script:` to `ActionScript 2.0`.  The first block of code I posted is the code you need to have your buttons navigate the frames.